# Is it unethical to switch jobs just after one year of coming onsite

Tags: job-offer, new-job, job-change, ethics, onsite

I work for an IT firm and got an onsite to US last year. Now I got an very good offer (45 percent hike plus perks) in a US MNC. I made sure that all my tasks are complete before I leave and completed the module.

Now the managers are saying that I am ditching the company and all. Is it really unethical as the time i served, I took care of stuff more than I was responsible for and worked late and all now they are saying that they can give a hike but i know that it can't anywhere go around a 50 pc hike.

Comment: It would be unethical not to switch! Also check this site; you will find some answered questions about accepting a raise after you told the company you would leave - it's rarely a good idea.

Comment: Same managers are probably mad because they will lose bonus money for being under budget on employee salary since it seems you were working for a fraction of your rate.

Comment: While I agree with these answers in general, one caveat, who paid to get you to the US and is there any Visa/Immigration sponsorship involved?  Those can be expensive and you should consider them in your current comp.

Comment: You already said you made sure all your tasks are complete. Did you give adequate notice before leaving and give opportunity for a knowledge transfer or transfer of responsibilities to a successor? If you do these things before leaving, it's definitely not "ditching the company".

Comment: Ethics be damned, this kind of BS logic coming from the managers is enough reason to leave the company. It is _never_ unethical to leave a company when you serve the agreed notice period (going absconding is another matter). It **is** unethical, however, for managers to use emotional blackmailing and other underhanded tricks to try to hold on to their employees.

Comment: A series of 1-2 year hops is usually a bad mark on your CV, but if you're being offered a 50% hike (please use the same notation in your post, rather than jumping between "percent" and "pc"), I'd say go with it. If you're honestly worth that much more, they were getting you for a steal, and had the chance to offer you more, or recognize that you were growing and evolving as an employee into a greater level of responsibility. That is unfortunate that they are accusing you of "ditching" them, but so be it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did they guarantee you a job for life and put your next 40years of salary into an escrow account when they hired you?

They wouldn't think twice about dumping you if they found somebody cheaper, or they needed to make an analyst's numbers this quarter.

Comment: I agree: a working relationship goes two ways. You are free to quit just as they are free to fire you. That's why things like trial period and notice period exist. If they want to keep talent, they should make the position attractive enough so people dont' want to leave.

Answer (score 12):

You were severely underpaid if you are getting 45% hike. What kind of sweatshop were you working for?
Nothing unethical in looking out for yourself, especially when you are being exploited.

Answer (score 6):

Obviously, this company thinks that you are some kind of slave, who has to be paid just because the law says so.

In reality, any contract can be terminated giving proper notice. When it does not fit the needs of both sides, it's time to move on. This is the case here.

You have found something better, go for it. I hope you don't have many doubts about whether the company would keep you if they didn't needed your services. In 99.99% of the companies they would get rid of you as soon as possible, and would not think whether it's too soon, or whether you really need the job.